# A question on p-factorable operators

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $1\leq p<\infty$. Suppose that an operator $T:X\rightarrow Y$ has a factorization $T=RS$, where $S:X\rightarrow l_{p}$, $R:l_{p}\rightarrow Y$ are compact operators.

Question: Let $\epsilon>0$. Are there operators $B:X\rightarrow l_{p}$, $A:l_{p}\rightarrow Y$ and $\lambda=(\lambda_{j})_{j}\in c_{0}$ such that $T=AM_{\lambda}B$, where $M_{\lambda}:l_{p}\rightarrow l_{p}, (t_{j})_{j}\rightarrow (\lambda_{j}t_{j})_{j}$ is the diagonal operator, and $\|A\|\cdot \sup_{j}|\lambda_{j}|\cdot \|B\|\leq (1+\epsilon)\|R\|\cdot \|S\|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If $T$ has finite rank this follows from the fact that every finite dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$ is contained in a finite dimensional superspace of $\ell_p$ that is $1+\epsilon$-isomorphic to the $L_p$ space of its dimension.

For the general case of compact $T$, write $T= \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n$ with each $T_n$ finite rank and $  \|T_n\| < 4^{-n}\epsilon$ for $n=1,2,\dots$.  Apply the finite rank case to each $T_n$ and take an $\ell_p$ sum.

Notice that every compact $T$ on $\ell_p$  satisfies the hypothesis you put on $T$.

Comment: Why the compact operator $T$ can be written as $\sum_{n}T_{n}$ with each $T_{n}$ finite rank and the norm of $T_{n}$ is less than $4^{-n}\epsilon$? Is this true for every compact operator?

Comment: Sure, if the target space has the approximation property.  It is elementary. Notice that the estimate applies to the \|T_n\| with $n>0$, not to $T_0$, which must have norm close to $\|T\|$.